# Can't populate Word Content Control with custom XML

Tags: c#, xml, replace, ms-word

I'm trying to write some code to populate a Word file with some Content Control using a XML file. For that I use the following code :

```
string outPath = @"D:\template_created.docx";
string docPath = @"D:\template.docx";
string xmlPath = @"D:\template.xml";

File.Copy(docPath, outPath);

using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(outPath, true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mdp = doc.MainDocumentPart;
    if (mdp.CustomXmlParts != null)
    {
        mdp.DeleteParts<CustomXmlPart>(mdp.CustomXmlParts);
    }

    CustomXmlPart cxp = mdp.AddCustomXmlPart(CustomXmlPartType.CustomXml);
    FileStream fs = null;

    try
    {
        fs = new FileStream(xmlPath, FileMode.Open);

        cxp.FeedData(fs);
        mdp.Document.Save();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (fs != null)
        {
            fs.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And here my XML file :

```
<root>
    <firstname_1>Marc</firstname_1>
    <lastname_1>Swit</lastname_1>
    <firstname_2>Paul</firstname_2>
    <lastname_2>Gevaert</lastname_2>
</root>
```

When I run the app, it created the custom XML file and append it to my Word file. When I open the Word file, there is no error, but all the Content Control are not filled

When I rename the template_created.docx to template_created.zip, extract files and explore them, I found my XML file correctly created and with the correct content in the customXML folder.

Someone have an idea to help me ?

Thanks !

Edit 17/08/15 : A first solution in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. In fact, firstly I need to create an XML file which contains all elements corresponding to my Contents Control and after use this file in [Word Content Control Toolkit](https://dbe.codeplex.com/) to append the XML with my Word file

After that when I run my app, the biding works and Content Control are populated